# How to match two clock signal's phases which are physically apart in two locations?

Tags: fpga, oscillator, clock, transmitter, receiver

Suppose, I have one Tx and one Rx physically separated by the long distance with clock signals CLK1 and CLK2 as shown in fig. (say both of 50MHz). 
[image]
I wish to align them in phases. By that I mean, rising edge of CLK1 and rising edge of CLK2 should match at any instance of time. How to achieve it?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "long distance".

Comment: Smells like an XY problem to me.

Comment: What accuracy are you looking for and for how long? Note that both clocks will drift with time and will not be equal in frequency so that their edges will never be in perfect alignment.

Comment: Why do they need to be aligned in phase, what are you actually trying to do? You don't need them both to be GPS synchronised for example if you are sending data from one to the other, the Rx clock can be derived from data embedded in the Tx stream.

Comment: If it is digital data, NRZI encoding will keep Rx Tx aligned.

Comment: @Andyaka Yeah, you are right. Actually I want to extract the phase information of other A/D converted analog signal [say sine(wt)] which is sampled at these CLK1 & CLK2 frequencies. I assume that if CLK1 = CLK2 = 50MHz then sampling with their phase aligned will give me similar data (forget noise and all at the moment),  In my first attempt, I'm unable to frame a proper question.  I'll re-edit according to your next reply or if can also edit to help me to express question prudently.

Comment: @Neil_UK Can you point me to any proper internet content or technical topic name where I can learn about Rx clock being derived fro data embedded in Tx stream. I want to explore how this mechanism work. Does it automatically derives clock frequency?

Answer (score 0):

An oscillator at each end that is phase locked to the WWV transmission on 10.0 MHz (as long as both sites can reliably receive that WWV transmission) would accomplish your need.  If the two sites are not to far apart the carrier (with the side-bands filtered out) of an am radio between them can be used to provide the reference frequency for your clock frequency synthesizers.  With more effort a GPS frequency standard or the carrier frequency of a (receivable by both sites) FM radio station could be used.
  These methods will result in two separate phase locked frequency standards.

Comment: Something like WWV or conventional broadcast carrier will not actually synchronize them unless they are equidistant (in the applicable path of propagation) from the transmitter.

Comment: What you say is true if the same phased is necessary without any adjustment, but a small stable time delay to either clock signal is all that would be needed to control the precise relative phase of the two.  This is commonly used for synchronous demodulation.  (using a DM74LS221 )